# Page not found after implementing "pretty URL" using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to add `.htaccess` in my PHP project but I've got a page not found error after converting URL to SEO friendly URL. I managed to change this URL but after changing I get a page not found error. How to reverse and get actual URL after converting?

My URL actually looks like this:

```
https://www.localhost/News/newsportal/news-details.php?catid=11
```

Contents of `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options All -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.]+)(?:.php)?\?catid=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]


# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]


# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?&catid=$2 [L,QSA]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Comment: You should also state what the "pretty" URL is expected to look like, without us having to "reverse engineer" your code (which could also be incorrect, given that it's not actually working as intended).

Comment: How did you get on with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your earlier redirect, your "pretty" URL is of the form `/News/newsportal/news-details/11`. This means that your internal rewrite from the "pretty URL" is incorrect:

> ```
> # internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
> RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?&catid=$2 [L,QSA]
> ```

You have 3 capturing subgroups in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, but only 2 backreferences in the *substitution* string (all are required). The *condition* will likely fail  (unless `/News/newsportal.php` exists as a physical file), so the rule is probably doing nothing (rather than rewriting to an invalid URL).

Your `RewriteRule` directive should be:

```
:
RewriteRule ^(.+/[^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?catid=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Although with your limited example, the regex could be further simplified to `^(.+)/([^/]+)/?$`